# Audio autoplay not working and no errors in console

Tags: html, audio

I have a website and I can't seem to figure out why the audio autoplay is not working.

I do not have errors in the console.

The code seems perfectly fine.

The website is www.galloautocenter.com.br

```
<audio class="audio" loop autoplay="autoplay" controls>
    <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but try it like this. Also, you don't specify what browser you're using. IE 8 and below do not support the `<audio>` tag or any attributes.

```
<audio class="audio" controls autoplay loop>
    <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</audio>
```

Comment: Already try and it does not work! Pretty weird. It only works in mozila but i have the audio files in mp3 and ogg that should have done the work in all browsers.

Comment: What other browsers are you trying it on? And what versions are they? IE8, Firefox 28, Chrome 26???

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<iframe class="audio" loop autoplay controls>
    <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</iframe>
```

or if you wanna play in background then,

```
<iframe class="audio" loop autoplay style = "display:none;">
    <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had proper solution for you. You must do any of this two steps.
Check your browser as shown on images, you had blocked Autoplay in browser.

[Auto-Play Policy Changes for macOS](https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/)

[Autoplay policy in Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)

[New  Policies for iOS](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/)

[Allow or block media autoplay in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay)

Second thing you can add this code to you any button on page

```html
    <!-- Html part-->
     <audio class="audio" loop autoplay="autoplay" controls id="audioelement">
        <source src="1.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
        <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
```

```js
  
    // JavaScript part
    
        var myAudio = document.getElementById("audioelement");
        myAudio.play();
```

It will not work on `window.onload = function () { }` etc. It will work only on elements where you can interact (Buttons). Or you must allow it in the browser.

```html
    <!-- Html part-->
    <button onclick="PlayAudio()">PlayAudio</button>
```

```js
    
    // JavaScript part
    function PlayAudio(){
        var audio = document.getElementById("audioelement");
        audio.play();
    }
```

Third thing you can make player elements visible and user can start or stop music by himself.